# Passing a constant value among controllers angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I have a constant value that is common throughout my project, among 2 of my modules- I want to have a design that I would have to only define it in one module and pass on the value to another module. How can I ?-
Module1 is like

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.constant('constVar', 'http://45.26365.23/mydata/');
```

and Module2 is like

```js
var Dashboardapp =angular.module('Dashboardapp', ['ui.router']);
Dashboardapp.constant('constVar', 'http://45.26365.23/mydata/');
```

Comment: you can put that constant in `$rootScope` & access it in any Controller of your app

Comment: @AgamBanga I'm not sure `$rootScope` can share a constant **between** apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive approach would be to define the constant outside the modules:

```
var myConstant = 'http://45.26365.23/mydata/';
```

or maybe even better if you have more constants or other general data:

```
var myConfig = {
    myConstant : 'http://45.26365.23/mydata/'
    // other data
}
```

and then call it in the modules:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.constant('constVar', myConfig.myConstant);

var Dashboardapp =angular.module('Dashboardapp', ['ui.router']);
Dashboardapp.constant('constVar', myConfig.myConstant);
```

Other possibility would be to define it in only one module, which would be your main module, and inject it in the other modules:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.constant('constVar', 'http://45.26365.23/mydata/');

var Dashboardapp =angular.module('Dashboardapp', ['ui.router', 'myApp']);
Dashboardapp.constant('constVar', myApp.constant);
```

Instead of the last line you could just call the constant where ever it is needed.

Comment: What about creating a separate module that contains all the constants and inject that module whenever/wherever you need it.

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day - newbie to angular, wasted 2 days on this ..pheww !!

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren Yes, that would be an enhanced and more elegant approach. Thank you for sharing your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the Google internal style guide says "do not define variables on the scope." (It actually explicitly says that). Note that means in particular, but not only, $rootScope (your code would be guaranteed to get kicked back in review if you did that, with very ugly "THIS IS BAD" comments).

Just define it at a higher level then both modules, typically at the app level (Angular 1.x defines a configurable place for constants in the app config API, you may want to look that up, this is useful because it actually enforces the constant). You can also just use a class defined in no module at all (just a top level class that you import and use statically), or you can define another module that you inject (which might be overkill for a few simple constants).

Comment: It seems we were both thinking of a similar approach. +1 for your explanation and mentioning the Google style guide, which emphasizes good and bad practices.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the 'constant' that Angular comes with ...

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

export default angular
  .module('app.constants.foo', [])
  .constant('fooAction', Object.freeze({
    name: value
  }))
  .name;
```

Then you inject your named constant. Thus it is accessible anywhere in the app (and more importantly immutable (mostly)).